# Confusion about two sentences

Tags: meaning, grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-choice

Sorry for my bad English. I have two sentences, can you tell me which sentence is correct.

> - "Examine the effectiveness of ModSecurity by penetration testing vulnerable Web Server"
> - "Examine the effectiveness of ModSecurity by performing vulnerable Web Server penetration testing".

If neither of them are correct, can you give me the correct one? Thanks in advance!.

Answer (score 2):

I would say:

> Examine the effectiveness of ModSecurity by performing a penetration
>   test on a vulnerable Web Server.

Comment: If I write this "Examine the effectiveness of ModSecurity by performing a penetration test on a real-based vulnerable Web Server", is it correct?

Comment: @HieuVoDuy Generally speaking yes, but keep in mind that *real-based* implies something reworked from a real thing, and does not quite equal *real*. So if it is a real vanilla web-server, then it is...a real vulnerable server, and if it is modified in some way for the learning purposes, than it is real-based. This difference in meaning is somewhat slight and you may not care.

Comment: I mean that web server is built base on real vulnerability, so "real-based" is correct, isn't it? Anyway, thank you for helping me and explaining difference between "real" and "real-based".